# Angularjs code not working in Chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, laravel, http-post, laravel-5

I built my application using Angularjs and Laravel. I use Firefox for development and testing, so I did not notice this until it was brought to my attention. My application works only in Firefox but not Chrome or Chrome-based browsers, I am also unable to trace the source of the problem.

I have a button directive that when clicked on executes a function to post data to the server, now this works fine in Firefox but not in Chrome, you would think that an issue like cross-browser compatibility not working would have something to do with client-side code but my application throws a 500 internal server error **ONLY** in Chrome or Chrome-based browsers.

I tested the function by posting an alert inside and the function was indeed getting called. I then went to the server side and found the controller that processed the request, removed the code within the assigned function and simply just did a

```
return "hello";
```

That still did not work, kept getting the same error. Next, instead of using my button directive I just used a normal html button and once again, I got the same error. I have no idea what is going on or how to solve it.

This is my function inside the controller:

```
$scope.event.addToCart = function(event, no_of_tickets, index) {
    $scope.selectedIndex = index;
    $scope.state = 'working';

    var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/buyEventTicket',
        headers: {
            'X-XSRF-Token': $("meta[name='csrf_token']").attr("content")
        },
        data: {
            event: event,
            no_of_tickets: no_of_tickets
        }
    }

    $http(req)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            $rootScope.$broadcast('TICKET_ADDED', true);

            $scope.selectedIndex = -1;
            $scope.state = 'ready';
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
            //alert(data);

        });

}
```

Previously, I checked to see what error was being thrown by the server and it was this:

```
DecryptException in Encrypter.php line 142: Invalid data.
```

**Note:** Since I am unable to pinpoint exactly the cause of the error, I do not know which portion of my code is relevant here.

Comment: What does the request/response between the browser and the server look like?  (Press F12 then look under the network tab) Any errors in the browser console window?

Comment: need to find out what is throwing the 500 error on server ...check the logs.. as well as do the request inspection as mentioned to see what is getting sent is as expected.

Comment: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" that is what is under the network tab

Comment: you already knew that it was throwing 500..check the headers and data sent also. Can also do a dump of `$_POST` to see that it is getting what you expect.

Comment: Previously i tried to see what was being returned it was this error page: "DecryptException in Encrypter.php line 142: Invalid data." Have no idea what that means especially since i am not encrypting or decrypting anything in that controller.

Comment: Even a var_dump of $_POST does not work, it looks like nothing inside that function in my controller on the server gets processed in chrome.

Comment: Your server has no idea it's talking to a chrome browser.  Compare the headers being sent between firefox and chrome.  I'm guessing it has something to do with your csrf token.  Maybe you can temporarily disable csrf protection.  Not sure why you have it anyways.  And $_POST is for posted form data.  Not going to help here.

Comment: oops yes...this is an angular request which puts data in the body and means you need to use `file_get_contents('php://input')` to access the json in request body instead of $_POST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change "X-XSRF-Token" to "X-CSRF-TOKEN". Note the difference between "XSRF" and "CSRF".

From the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#csrf-protection): "Note: The difference between the X-CSRF-TOKEN and X-XSRF-TOKEN is that the first uses a plain text value and the latter uses an encrypted value, because cookies in Laravel are always encrypted. If you use the csrf_token() function to supply the token value, you probably want to use the X-CSRF-TOKEN header."

Additionally, the documentation states that the the encrypted XSRF token is stored in a XSRF-TOKEN cookie, and that Angular will already pick up this value for you. According to Angular's [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http): "When performing XHR requests, the $http service reads a token from a cookie (by default, XSRF-TOKEN) and sets it as an HTTP header (X-XSRF-TOKEN)." Therefore, it seems like you can remove trying to manually set the token altogether, and the frameworks should handle it for you.

Comment: I tried it before, "X-CSRF-TOKEN" and laravel kept throwing a token mismatch exception, however when i changed it to "X-XSRF-TOKEN" it worked, but only in firefox.

Comment: Anyway i took the hint and commented this line out "'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken" in my Kernel.php, it works fine now. :)

Comment: @user3718908 While that is an option, it is making your site less secure by allowing CSRF attacks. Did you try getting rid of your `headers` key in your `req` object?

Comment: @user3718908 Also, one final option would be to just add the `_token` field to your request data, so that the _token is coming through like a normal form request.